# JS: trying to use setTimeout with incremental values

Tags: javascript, delay, settimeout, intervals

I am trying to set up some delays on a loop using incremental IDs in my function call, as well as incrementally larger delay times.  What I have set up is like this:

```
var delay = 0;
var delayMilliseconds = 250;
timeOutArray = [];

for(var i=0; i<100; i++){
    delay = i*delayMilliseconds;

    timeOutArray[i] = setTimeout(function(){
            loadRoute(modelsArray[i], (i+1));
        },delay);
}
```

The problem I am running into is that by the time any of the loadRoute() functions get called, the "i" being referenced has already been incremented to 99.

I am looking for a way to make it recognize the number of "i" at the moment I set the Timeout, rather than the moment the Timeout occurs.

I found this article about using "promises", but is a bit confusing.
[Javascript - Wait the true ending of a function that uses setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625439/javascript-wait-the-true-ending-of-a-function-that-uses-settimeout)

Could someone please show me know to implement promises into these calls, or anything that can do it without wrapping the setTimeout code all in an eval()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the working example of your code. The problem is misunderstanding of **Scope & Closure**.

```
var delay = 0;
var delayMilliseconds = 250;
timeOutArray = [];

for (var i=1; i<100; i++) {
    (function(j){
        delay = j*delayMilliseconds;
        timeOutArray[j] = setTimeout(function(){
            console.log(j)
            //loadRoute(modelsArray[j], (j+1));
        },delay);
    })( i );
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
(function(j){
 //this part of the code create new scope
})( i );
```

The use of **above function** inside each iteration created a **new scope** for each **iteration**, which gave our **timeout** function callbacks the **opportunity to close over a new scope for each iteration**, one which had a variable with the right per-iteration value in it for us to access.

[Source - For more info](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/ch5.md)

Comment: Thank you so much.  This solved my issue inside the existing context of my code.  Also, it is good to know I need to study up on Scope & Closure.

Comment: If it helps, then please accept the answer, It may help other users.

Answer (score 0):

Save it in a closure to preserve the original value.

```
timeOutArray[i] = setTimeout( (function(i) { return function(){
    loadRoute(modelsArray[i], (i+1));
}) (i),delay);
```

Basically, you're creating and executing a new anonymous function in each loop iteration and pass a copy of the current `i` to it. Upon executing, this function returns another anonymous function that is then passed to `setTimeout`. This function, however, retains a reference to the scope in which it was created and thus sees the `i` as saved by the outer anonymous function.

It's a little tricky. You can google on closures in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I actually get a syntax error with that code though on this line:

`}) (i),delay);`

SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Answer (score 0):

Either that, or define your timeout function outside of the for loop and call that:

```
var delay = 0;
var delayMilliseconds = 250;

function doTimeoutStuff(i, delay) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        loadRoute(modelsArray[i], (i+1));
    }, delay);
}

for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    delay = i*delayMilliseconds;
    doTimeoutStuff(i, delay);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a closure, `setTimeout()` allows you to pass variables to be passed to the callback function on execution which will then live inside and for the duration of the callback.

`setTimeout(function[, delay, arg1, arg2, ...]);`

Source: [MDN - setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)