# How to make a function wait for another to stop executing(Simon Game) javascript

Tags: javascript

I’m making a Simon Game and I’ve already added the logic but I don’t know how to pause an execution until the player has pressed on a tile. I’ve made a function called `user()` that records users input and pushes it to the `userSeq` array. Then I made a function `checkTurn()` to check who’s turn is next (the computer or the user). If it’s the user’s turn then I want in the else to wait for the `user()` function to finish and then call the `callcheckClicks()` to check if user’s input is the same as computer’s and then continue to the new level. Please help!

Here’s a link: https://codepen.io/Teo03/pen/yPvbwY

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var green = document.getElementById("green");
  var red = document.getElementById("red");
  var yellow = document.getElementById("yellow");
  var blue = document.getElementById("blue");
  var tile = document.getElementsByClassName("tile");
  //audio for every click
  var audio = [
    new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3"),
    new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound2.mp3"),
    new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound3.mp3"),
    new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound4.mp3")
  ];
  // record the round
  var round = 0;
  // record the random presses
  var compSeq = [];
  //record user clicks
  var userSeq = [];
  //if it's false computer moves
  var turn = false;
  //round number
  var round = 0;
  //count how many moves user does
  var playerIndex = 0;

  //start
  $(".start").click(function() {
    round++;
    turn = false;
    $("#round")
      .html("Round: " + round)
      .show();
    $(".start, .reset").hide();
    checkTurn();
  });

  function addNewRandomNumber() {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
    computer(random);
    console.log("random" + random);
  }

  // call the computer to make an action
  function callComp() {
    addNewRandomNumber();
    enableClicks();
    turn = true;
    checkTurn();
  }

  function callCheckClicks() {
    checkClicks();
  }

  //check every time the user clicks if the user clicks are the same as the computer's
  function checkClicks() {
    console.log("random clicks: " + compSeq);
    //if user guess is correct
    if (userSeq[playerIndex] == compSeq[playerIndex]) {
      if (userSeq[playerIndex].length == compSeq[playerIndex].length) {
        // if they are then it's computer's turn
        callComp();
      } else {
        playerIndex += 1;
        $(".start")
          .html("Next")
          .show();
        // user is right, he can continue inputting another clicks if the sequence has
        checkTurn();
      }
    } else {
      resetUserVariables(); // user is wrong
    }
  }
  //reset playerIndex
  function resetUserVariables() {
    playerIndex = 0;
  }
  //press a random button
  function computer(ran) {
    switch (ran) {
      case 1:
        blink(green);
        audio[0].play();
        compSeq.push(1);
        break;
      case 2:
        blink(red);
        audio[1].play();
        compSeq.push(2);
        break;
      case 3:
        blink(blue);
        audio[2].play();
        compSeq.push(3);
        break;
      case 4:
        blink(yellow);
        audio[3].play();
        compSeq.push(4);
        break;
      default:
        return;
    }
    console.log("random clicks: " + compSeq);
    enableClicks();
    turn = true;
    checkTurn();
  }
  //blink a tile
  function blink(tile) {
    $(tile).fadeOut("slow", function() {
      $(this).fadeIn("slow", function() {
        return;
      });
    });
  }

  //user input
  function user() {
    if ($(this).is("#green")) {
      userSeq.push(1);
      audio[0].play();
      blink(green);
      playerIndex++;
    } else if ($(this).is("#red")) {
      userSeq.push(2);
      audio[1].play();
      blink(red);
      playerIndex++;
    } else if ($(this).is("#blue")) {
      userSeq.push(3);
      audio[2].play();
      blink(blue);
      playerIndex++;
    } else if ($(this).is("#yellow")) {
      userSeq.push(4);
      audio[3].play();
      blink(yellow);
      playerIndex++;
    }
    turn = false;
    checkTurn();
    console.log("user clicks: " + userSeq);
  }

  //add an event listener for user clicks
  function enableClicks() {
    for (var i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
      tile[i].addEventListener("click", user, false);
    }
  }
  //disable clicks when is computer's turn
  function disableClicks() {
    for (var i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
      tile[i].removeEventListener("click", user, false);
    }
  }
  //check who's turn is next
  function checkTurn() {
    if (turn === false) {
      //call computer
      callComp();
    } else {
      callCheckClicks();
    }
  }
  //document.ready().
});
```

```css
html * {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

h3 {
  display: none;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.circle {
  background: #d3d3d3;
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid gray;
  margin: auto;
}

.tile {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
  border-top-right-radius: 100%;
}

#green {
  background-color: green;
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
}

#yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
}

btn {
  padding-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="text-center">Simon Game</h1>
<div class="container text-center">
  <h3 id="round">Round: </h3>
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="tile" onclick="user()" id="green"></div>
    <div class="tile" onclick="user()" id="red"></div>
    <div class="tile" onclick="user()" id="yellow"></div>
    <div class="tile" onclick="user()" id="blue"></div>
  </div>
  <a class="btn start btn-default">Start</a>
  <a class="btn reset btn-default" onclick="reset()">Reset</a>

  <!-- container !-->
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is so complicated to read.. please choose suspicous parts

Comment: I think the problem is in the checkTurn() function because everytime after the computer plays it calls that function and it executes the code in the else statement and calls checkClicks() without waiting the user() function to finish and I don't know how to wait there for user input.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is `setTimeout()`

This takes 2 parameters, your function and the number of milliseconds.

For example if you want to execute a function after three seconds of an onclick event...

```
<button onclick="setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert('Hello');
}
</script>
```

Then use a promise like explained here:
[Javascript - Wait the true ending of a function that uses setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625439/javascript-wait-the-true-ending-of-a-function-that-uses-settimeout)

Another thing to note is the flow of the program.  Currently you are using a `checkTurn` method that calls a `callCheckClicks` method that calls a `checkClicks` and `checkClicks` calls `checkTurn` again.  With this your program will end up crashing as it continuously loops forever.  In order to do this you need to activate your `if/else` within your `checkClicks` to have

```
turn = true;
checkTurn();
```

To look like

```
function checkClicks() {
  console.log("random clicks: " + compSeq);
  //if user guess is correct
  if (userSeq[playerIndex] == compSeq[playerIndex]) {
    if (userSeq[playerIndex].length == compSeq[playerIndex].length) {
      // if they are then it's computer's turn
      callComp();
    } else {
      playerIndex += 1;
      $(".start")
        .html("Next")
        .show();

      // user is right, he can continue inputting another clicks if the sequence has
      turn=true;

      checkTurn();

    }
  } else {
    resetUserVariables(); // user is wrong
  }
}
```

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: but as I said I don't know how to wait for the user to input and then continue executing the checkClick() function to see if the user input is the same as the computer's

Comment: `function callCheckClicks() {
    checkClicks();
    turn = true;
    checkTurn();
  }` should I add that here?

Comment: @Teo I also included the snippet where I believe an endless recursive function may be crashing the program.

Comment: I changed the `checkClicks()` function as you said and now every time I click **Start**  it's ok, but when I press on any tile it crashes again. I really don't know where is the problem.

Comment: @Teo check to make sure you have a close  } for every { .  When i first tried to run the snippet in another environment, it wouldnt start because there was an extra { at the bottom.

Comment: I checked but it looks it's alright I really don't know where this loop is happening

Comment: I see the same too the problem is all the tiles blink at the same time when one of them is clicked

Comment: @Teo Yea I see what you're saying now, I'm not sure. Seems like a recursive function is getting abused somewhere.  I'm not sure where it is yet I have to look a bit more.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your help and if you need more time I will wait :)